# How can we adjust p:commandbutton size or width

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

My working environment is: Primefaces 4.0 with JSF 2.0
My aim is to set width of command button same in the form. I find `style="font-size:10px"` to set button's font size which is changing button's label size. I want to change button's size

Comment: What stopping you to do that ? Button have width and height right ?

Comment: i want to set button's own width not its font-size, because i have multiple buttons together, UI not looking atractive

Comment: `<p:commandButton value="..." style="width: 100px; height:100px; text-align: right"/>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the style attribute in the commandButton with the css properties width and height.

```
<p:commandButton id="button" value="Click"                              
                 actionListener="#{myBean.doAction}" 
                 style="width:100px;height:100px"/>
```

To set the same value for all the commandButtons on a page,add the following css to your jsf page.

```
       .ui-button{
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
        }
```

Comment: Is there a better way than choosing pixels? What if the theme is changed?

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to play with the CSS, for example, i don't like that much space between buttons and their borders (it looks so big when are 2 or three buttons side by side, or they look bigger with text surround them), so, I first make the font smaller (the old font-size: .8em) and then a override the padding of the button (yes, the padding is huge in the buttons, at least for me), something like:

```
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text {
    padding: .1em .5em;
}
```

Comment: Yup, i have to align them veritically, in a column that's why, i have to set them in a same size

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using **style="min-width: 15em;"** because the button may be inside a PanelGroup and the **width** property will not work.

```
<h:panelGrid columnClasses="column_left" columns="2" style="padding-top:8px;" styleClass="acciones">
 <h:panelGroup>
 <p:commandButton update="@all"  style="min-width: 15em;"> </p:commandButton>
 </h:panelGroup>                    
 </h:panelGrid>
```