# How to resize button in primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, xhtml

In Primefaces ShowCase is an example how to use an effects. One of these I used for button - resize.

```
    <p:commandButton type="button" value="Show" style="width:200px" icon="ui-icon-image">
        <p:effect type="size" event="mouseover">
            <f:param name="to" value="{width:300}" />
        </p:effect>
    </p:commandButton>
```

Similar example is on [this page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/effect.xhtml) "Size"

It works, but after the button resize to 300px it come bak to original size. And I want to resize it to 300px and stop it on this size. It is possible? How?

Hope you understand what I try to do. Thank you.

Comment: seems the same question was discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905179/how-can-we-adjust-pcommandbutton-size-or-width

Comment: It is not same. I need to do an effect to resize button width and stay on this width. On this page [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905179/how-can-we-adjust-pcommandbutton-size-or-width) is not used effect

Comment: @bmscomp: no it is not. The link you refer to does not contain any relation to effects

Comment: Try you use an effect that fires on mouseout... might even be that `<p:effect type="size" event="mouseout">
            <f:param name="to" value="{width:300}" />
        </p:effect>` just work

Comment: Do I understand that you need an affect that runs once ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your button to reset to 200px then you'd better use pure jQuery.

Here is a working example:

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="expandableBtn" type="button" value="Show" style="width: 200px" icon="ui-icon-image" />

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery(function () {
     $('.expandableBtn').on('mouseover', function() {
          $(this).css('width', '300px');
     });
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

If you want to take advantage of the "transition effect" then replace `$(this).css('width', '300px');` with:

```
$(this).animate({
    width: '300px'
}, 1000, function () {
    // Transition complete
});
```

Where 1000 is the duration (in ms) of the transition.